# Open Set Containing a Single Axis of the 2-D Real Plane

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the set containing only the "$x$-axis" of the real 2-D plane (that is $A = \{(x, y) : x \in \mathbb{R}, y = 0\}$). Then, any open set $E$ containing $A$ must contain a set $B$ of the form $$B = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{x\}\times\{(-r_x, r_x)\}.$$ It was stated in the solution to a problem I had read that since the number of points along the $x$-axis is uncountable, there must exist a countable sequence of distinct numbers along the axis, call it $\{x_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that $r_{x_k} > 1/N$ for large enough $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Why is it the case that such a countable sequence of distinct numbers must exist?

I thought of trying to construct the countable sequence in the following manner: pick any number $x_1$ along the $x$-axis, by the Archimedean property of the real numbers $r_{x_1} > 0$ implies $ r_{x_1} > 1/N_1$ for some $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Subsequently choose a second number $x_2$ along the $x$-axis. Similarly, $r_{x_2} > 1/N_2$ for some $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$. Take $\tilde{N_2} = \min\{1/N_1, 1/N_2\}$. Then, $r_{x_1} > 1/\tilde{N_2}$ and $r_{x_2} > 1/\tilde{N_2}$. I realized that I can't just continue to iterate in this fashion, however, because my $\tilde{N}_k$ may just increase unboundedly as the sequence grows in length. Something tells me that I should somehow be using the uncountability of the real line as is intimated by the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each integer $N \geq 1$, let $B_N = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} : r_x > \frac{1}{N}\right\}$.  Using the Archimedean property (as you did in your post) we have that for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is an $N$ such that $r_x > 1/N$, so $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}B_N$.

We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, while the union of countably many finite sets is countable, so there must be some $N$ such that $B_N$ is infinite; choosing any sequence from $B_N$ will give you what you want.

By the way, the union of countably many countable sets is also countable, so the same argument here also shows that there is some $N$ where $B_N$ is uncountable, so we can get much more than just a sequence, but it sounds like a sequence is all you needed.

Comment: @joriki yes, you are right.  I was in the middle of editing it to simplify that (and also not bother making the sets disjoint, since it complicates the notation for no benefit).

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't think I've ever used the fact that the union of countably many finite sets is countable in such a way. Will be sure to add this to my toolbox of useful stuff to bear in mind.